# Connect to my LAN from outside my router (WAN)?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, dd-wrt

Time for some extremely rough ASCII art.

```
     |------|          /LAN_B
ME ->|ROUTER|->LAN_A-> -LAN_C
     |------|          \LAN_D
```

LAN_A is a server with the necessary exposed port(s) to connect to. Basically, I'm wondering if there's any way for me to connect, from outside of my LAN, to LAN_A, and through it, connect to any of the other computers on my LAN as if I were actually on the LAN (RDP, FTP, any service, really - as if I were actually on the LAN). Sorry if this seems like an ambiguous explanation, but I basically just want it to be as if I were really on the LAN and for each other computer on the LAN to have their own IP address that I can send or receive connections to.

My router is running dd-wrt, so if I could actually just connect to my router, that would be great, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I do this all the time.  If by "SSH server" you mean an actual computer running an SSH server, then you would SSH from outside into LAN_A, and get a command line on LAN_A.  You would then run another `ssh` command on LAN_A to connect to one of the other machines.

Just make sure your router is configured to forward port 22 from the external interface to LAN_A.

Answer to updated question:

You could access a particular port by using SSH port forwarding.  For example:

```
ssh host -l1234:LAN_B:5678
```

Would connect to `host` and forward port 1234 on your 'ME' machine to LAN_B's port 5678.  You could then connect to `localhost:1234` and you would really be connecting to `LAN_B:5678`.

Alternatively you could investigate SSH's `-D` option, which provides a local SOCKS proxy server, which forwards connections over the secure channel.  If you set your application to use the `localhost` SOCKS proxy, then you could connect directly to LAN_B, C, and D.

However using SSH for this is not the ideal way to go, as SSH was designed for point-to-point communication.  If you have control over the ME computer and LAN_A, I would recommend looking into [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net) instead, which can make LAN_A through LAN_D appear as if they are on the same network segment as your ME computer, while encrypting all communication over the Internet channel just like SSH.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without any of the other machines having an SSH server? Sorry, I should have specified that in the main post, I'll update it.

Comment: @Huskehn: SSH is a specific way of connecting to a computer.  You can't SSH to something if it's not running an SSH server.  Do you mean you want to connect to the other machines in a different way?  If so, please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: Updated my question again. Hopefully it's somewhat easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I'll definitely look into OpenVPN. Thanks!